# A metaphor for something that changes for a narrative about my name

Tags: metaphors, figures-of-speech, figurative

I am writing a narrative for a class and I have been stuck on metaphors for a specific part!

My name has changed quite a few times throughout my life and I wanted to highlight this through use of metaphors but I can't find any that would fit. I want to do a sentence that is

> My name was [name] all the way until I was born, then it was (A) [metaphor].

And I've been considering stuff like "moving target" but none of it feels right. I want something with the right feel in order to indicate that at first my name felt so simple but then it had to be changed so many times.

Comment: '... almost as changeable as the weather.' I won't post this as an 'answer' as it might be too changeable. The metaphor here is in the simile format, of course.

Comment: ...., then it was in flux

Comment: *Malleable* maybe?

Comment: There are variable associations. Something that is ever changing might be annoying (trying to hit a moving target), or dangerous (shifting sands), or attractive (the seasons/turning leaves/sparkling light on water), or useful (a master of disguise), or reflect wider changes and be a metaphor for something else. And it might change slowly and regularly, suddenly, gradually, intermittently, or constantly. I think your trouble finding a metaphor is because you need to think exactly what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

"A moveable feast" is strictly a celebration that falls on different days, but can be used as a [metaphor](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/movable-feast.html).

> 'Movable feast' has been adopted into the language as a metaphor for things which change over time.

If you say "My name is a moveable feast" that is a narrative which could also imply that you are a person who is worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is odd. I don't suppose there is a metaphor for that. Here is my stab at it.

> My name was [Gold] all the way until I was born, then it was
> [malleable like gold].
>
> My name was [a solid one] all the way until I was born, then it was
> [plastic].
>
> My name was [good] all the way until I was born, then it was
> [plastic].
>
> My name was [good] all the way until I was born, then it was
> [protean].

[Plastic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plastic) (Wiktionary) :(archaic) Any solid but malleable substance. (It is making a comeback in neuro-sciences)

[Protean](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protean) (Wiktionary) : Exceedingly variable; readily assuming different shapes or forms.